# How to send secret data from JS to PHP Without Showing On Debugger?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a small gamey thing. I have to create another minigame inside the real game. I did tho. But the minigame is made with JS, the variables like earning points are javascript variables. I have to send them to PHP but there are 2 problems.
1- If I hold my variables in JS, they can be open to the debugger tool, so anyone who knows how to edit some variables will earn point easily. It affects the main game too. I have to prevent them to change variables via the debugger tool. I don't know how to...

And secondly.

2- I can't send that with AJAX or POST&GET because I had to do things immediately on one page. 
Its something like, you have to press a box as much as you can. And the count of that presses are going to javascript via the onclick method, I have to hold that variable hidden until the person presses "OK, Enough" button.
I don't want to use a hidden input method, because anyone who can read HTML can easily find and edit the hidden input, I want that minigame to be fully uncheatable.

How? thanks.

**EXAMPLE CODE**

```
<button onmouseover="test();">HOVER</button>
<button>STOP</button>

<script>var counter = 0; function test(){counter++;}</script>
```

When someone hovers the HOVER button, it increases the counter. Whenever he presses STOP, I want to send counter data to PHP but, I don't want anybody to change the counter value via f12(debugger tool).

Comment: Hey OP, welcome to SO. Please check out the [asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and add a specific example of the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Also, because JS is run in a user's browser, it's fundamentally unavoidable that they could follow your code in the debugger. Your best bet is probably obfuscation; use a [minifier](https://jscompress.com/).

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, the frontend is transparent to end users. Any obfuscation methods only increase the difficulty and time to cheat.

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't try to use any hiding methods. I know someone can cheat into javascript whatever I do.

Comment: Even if you make your js code to some extent secure, it's still possible to intercept network with exteenal network debugging tools. Then a cheater could send requests directly even if he isn't playing the game.  If it's both easy to exploit and critical to your main game, you should consider move such logic to server side or redesign the logic.

Comment: I have to use methods like onclick, onmouseover, etc. As I mentioned down below,  I don't know how to use WebSockets exactly. Is there a way to use those methods without javascript? like isn't there any way to make php understand what's going on the client side? like seeing mouse moves or some php values that increase on every press?

Comment: @M.Uslu, PHP can't see any client side events b/c it's a server side language. Browsers cannot run php. The page that browsers see is preprocessed by php before it gets served. Javascript can see the clientside events and so can your users.

Comment: @Dov Rine; thank you. I change my mind, going to make complete another strategy for the mini-game.

Answer (score 0):

The other posters are correct. Javascript in the browser in insecure and there's nothing you can do about it.

You might be able to use a websocket instead of ajax, to send the click events to the server.
The server would generate and send responses through the websocket back to the client.

Comment: I don't know how to use WebSocket, I have another game with Node.JS and Socket IO and works well, but It takes me too much time to make that socket game, lots of searches, copy codes. etc. I don't know if I can combine pure PHP with node.js, and I don't want to screw my progress on this project. Is there a way to make a minigame on commands like onclick etc? do you have any idea?

Comment: You can't combine php with node. A quick search turns up a ton of PHP websocket tutorials, though. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=websockets+in+php&atb=v140-3__&ia=web